# Запуск проекта Asp.Net Core на IIS поддерживающий FrameWork 4.6.1

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-core

Написал Web Api Core приложение. Но заказчик не может установить дополнительные модули у себя на сервере (нельзя перезагружать, слишком много сайтов на сервере).
Сменил фреймворк (https://jonhilton.net/2016/09/07/using-asp-net-core-against-net-4-6/) 
 
Но осталась проблема - сервер IIS не может прочитать Web.config

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <system.webServer>
    <handlers>
      <add name="aspNetCore" path="*" verb="*" modules="AspNetCoreModule" resourceType="Unspecified" />
    </handlers>
    <aspNetCore processPath=".\API.exe" arguments="" stdoutLogEnabled="false" stdoutLogFile=".\logs\stdout" forwardWindowsAuthToken="false" />
  </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

Ошибка HTTP 500.19 — Internal Server Error 
Как изменить web.config, чтобы приложение, опубликованное из проекта Web Api Core (с использованием FW 4.6.1) стало работать на IIS, без доп.модулей?

Comment: Решено путем установки обновлений на сервер и перезагрузки. Пришлось пойти на это. Иначе файлы не читались.

Answer (score 0):

[Вот](https://github.com/dotnet/core/blob/master/release-notes/download-archives/2.0.0-download.md#windows-server-hosting) что написано в документации к `NET Core`.

Шаги простые:

1. Установите на сервере с IIS [DotNetCore.2.0.0-WindowsHosting.exe](https://download.microsoft.com/download/B/1/D/B1D7D5BF-3920-47AA-94BD-7A6E48822F18/DotNetCore.2.0.0-WindowsHosting.exe)
2. В IIS создаёте пул с парметром `.NET CLR version: No Managed Code`
3. Добавляете приложение с указанием папки, куда вы сделали `dotnet publish`

При `publish` у вас должен появиться `web.config` или же добавьте его сами в корень проекта.